# How to do the WP8 background effect in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to build a WP8 home screen in Compose, in which each tile can be transparent, and show the image background underneath (w/ parallax effect).

[image: WP8 demo]

Currently the whole list is basically in [a custom Grid Composable](https://github.com/louis993546/Metro-Compose/blob/main/demo/src/main/java/com/louis993546/metro/demo/VerticalTilesGrid.kt), and each tile don't know what other tiles exist

Any idea on how to do this effect in Jetpack Compose?

- I can't just add background and then set each tile to transparent, because all of the gaps are also transparent, so it would just look like all the icons and text floating
- Technically I might be able to draw all the gaps out to a separate layer above, but that just seems even more inefficient than it already is
- Something like `BlendMode` seems like what I am looking for, but I have no idea how to get `Canvas` and the custom `Layout` to talk to each other on which part to blend together? (And also which `blendMode` it should be)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you customize the colour of the gaps anyhow?

Comment: @MARSK if you mean "is that allow per design", no, it's just the same as the background background (i.e. white on light mode or black on dark mode); if you mean is that technically possible: maybe? Currently all the gaps are gaps because they have nothing. But if I do all the math and convert them to like dozens or hundreds of rectangles, then yes I can set the color for each of them and have them lay on top, but that just seems stupidly inefficient